# First post not in review list?

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-lists

[Here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27306/users-database-with-different-access-level-and-information) is a question from Joey, which is his first post on DBA.SE (his user profile shows exactly one question and no answers so far).  However, the first posts review list is empty (and today's listing shows zero reviews).  Shouldn't this post show up in this list?

### EDIT

Recently I experience the same problem regularly.  An example is [this one](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/28498/6219).

Comment: great question and idk

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was a bug that was fixed this weekend.

Comment: Thanks, Geoff.  I've just seen a similar one (this time an answer): http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27507/6219

Comment: Another one, this time I would have expected to show up amongst late answers: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27643/6219

Comment: @GeoffDalgas this is still happening. Here is another example http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30162/mysql-replication-delay-very-serious

Comment: Accepted the answer in a timely fashion, as I don't see the issue popping up anymore.