# First Posts Reviews not working

Tags: support, review-lists

Back in October, dezso asked [this question](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/810/first-post-not-in-review-list) which is flagged as bug fixed. However, I'm still seeing the issue that a user's first  post is not showing up in the first post review list. Here is an example:

[mysql replication delay very serious](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30162/mysql-replication-delay-very-serious)

Comment: Just to add something hopefully valuable: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/30228/6219
which is a first post, probably no one has reviewed it (it was very young at the time of writing) and not in the queue.

Comment: Also, http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/30229/6219

Comment: So, it looks like it turns up in the queue later: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7234511#7234511  This way I must suppose there is a time treshold after which new posts get queued.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to my research, trygvis did review it: https://dba.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/5569 and about 90 minutes before you asked this, give or take.

Additionally, let me show you how I got there :D

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Interesting. Your first screen showing the number of First Posts to review...Mine shows '0', not 1.

Comment: You're all working from the same queue, @DTest, so that number will change constantly as new items are added and removed.

Comment: @Shog9 hm, perhaps my question would better be 'how does the review queue work' then...because I assumed those things had to be reviewed by X amount of users before being cleared.From the looks of it, a single user (with appropriate rep) will clear it out?

Comment: @DTest: well, you're limited to 20 reviews per day, so depending on traffic and dedication one person *may* be able to clear it or may not.

Comment: @Shog9 That's fine, I had thought there was some redundancy checks (like it takes 2 users per first post to review before it clears out). If not, this is WAI and I'll accept jcole's answer

Comment: Also keep in mind my screenshot was taken like 30 minutes after the question was asked. I believe it even got resolved while I was posting the answer.

Comment: Additional relevant links should include: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139536/new-feature-community-review-tasks-now-in-beta and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange

Comment: In the history I can see only my own reviews - this is b/c of rep, I suppose.

Comment: Probably so. Also, I'm sometimes amazed at what can't be seen, I should ask about the review history...